# findAndModify - MongoError: exception: must specify remove or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, findandmodify

Id like to update an array and return the doc.  Is my findAndModify syntax correct?

```
this.becomeFollower = function(title, username, callback){
    "use strict"

    posts.findAndModify({
        query: {"title":title, "roster":"yes"},
        update: { "$addToSet": { "followers":username } },
        new: true,
        upsert: true
        }, 
        function(err, doc){
            console.log('find and modified  ' +doc);
        });

}
```

I had no problem using this:

```
    posts.update({"title":title, "roster":"yes"}, { "$addToSet": { "followers":username } }, function(err, roster){
        "use strict"
        if(err) return callback(err, null);
        callback(err, roster);
    });
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#upsert-and-unique-index `When findAndModify() includes the upsert: true option and the query field(s) is not uniquely indexed, the method could insert a document multiple times in certain circumstances.` I guess that's why `sort` is needed.

Comment: well, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648693/4597306 helps finally. Also https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Comment: Attention please: the [.findAndModify()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) method in the node native driver implementation is different from the mongo shell implementation. See also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326067/1335142

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the [docs for node-mongodb findAndModify](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify); the signature looks like:

```
collection.findAndModify(query, sort, update, options, callback)
```

So you should do:

```
  posts.findAndModify(
    {"title":title, "roster":"yes"},
    [['_id','asc']],
    { "$addToSet": { "followers":username } },
    {new: true, upsert: true}, 
    function(err, doc){
        console.log('find and modified  ' +doc);
    }
  );
```

The `sort` argument is probably optional, but it's unclear so I included it in the example.

Comment: YOUR THE MAN! THANK U! I thought that was a little unclear here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: Why is sort not surrounded by {}?

Comment: Sort is an array, where each element is itself an array with the first element is a key to sort on, and the second element is the sort direction. Arrays are surrounded by square brackets.