# NodeJS and MongoDB FindAndModify() need remove or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

im  trying to do a findAndModifiy in mongodb with nodejS, This is my code:

```
var nextBill = function (db, success, log) {
    var collection = db.collection('autoincrements');
    log.debug('autoIncrementRepository', 'nextBill');
    var result = collection.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: 'auto' },
        update: { $inc: { bill: 1 } },
        new: true
    });

    success(result.bill);
};
```

EDIT:

Try with callback

```
collection.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: 'auto' },
        update: { $inc: { bill: 1 } },
        new: true
    }, function (e, result) {
        success(result.budget);
    });
```

But give me the error need remove or update..But im doing it..

Comment: Which driver are you using? The MongoDB node native driver requires a callback, so does mongoose, so does monk and others.

Comment: Native driver, but using callback i get the same error:. I will edit my awnser with my actually code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) method in the node native driver implementation is different from the mongo shell implementation. To do an update as above you do:

```
collection.findAndModify(
   { "_id": "auto" },
   { "$inc": { "bill": 1 } },
   function(err,doc) {
     // work here

   }
);
```

Oddly somewhat to remove you specify in options so the same would "remove" the matched document:

```
collection.findAndModify(
   { "_id": "auto" },
   { "$inc": { "bill": 1 } },
   { "remove": true },
   function(err,doc) {
     // work here

   }
);
```

The main difference being you do not name the "key" sections for the actions.

Comment: Thanks this works, but why have they differed from the shell spec / what the docs say??

Comment: @Aodh the shell spec is not a spec for driver implementations.  The docs you're reading are for mongo itself, not the driver.  Read the driver documentation found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/

Comment: Hi, am still getting error, here is my code
db.collection(nextIDCollection).findAndModify({"_id":1},{$inc: {"nextID":1}} ,function(err,doc){});
I could not find whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 10):

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findAndModify

This above document specifies that the second parameter is the sort order for choosing which document to use if multiple ones match the query. Only giving two parameters will result in the "need remove or update" error message.

```
collection('MyCollection').findAndModify(
    { _id: "auto" },
    [],
    { $inc: { "bill": 1 } },
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err,doc) {
       // work here
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Hi I have followed this and it worked perfectly.

db.collection('test').findAndModify(
  {hello: 'world'}, // query
  [['_id','asc']],  // sort order
  {$set: {hi: 'there'}}, // replacement, replaces only the field "hi"
  {}, // options
  function(err, object) {
      if (err){
          console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
      }else{
          console.dir(object);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this It worked for me in nodejs

```
users.findAndModify(
           { "_id": userid,"password":pwd},
           [['_id', 'asc']],
           { "$set":{"password":npwd}},
           {"upsert":false}
        ,function(err,result){
        //enter code here

    })
```