# Mongodb findAndModify node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Following code gives me an exception in node js saying: "need to remove or update"

```
var args = {
    query: { _id: _id },
    update: { $set: data },
    new: true,
    remove: false
};

db.collection(COLLECTION.INVENTORY_LOCATION)
    .findAndModify(args, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            callback(null, results);
        }
    });
```

Not able to figure out the issue as I have specified the update operation.

Comment: Perhaps it is because you have supplied both arguments? Try only specifying the `update` parameter and leaving out the `remove`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The syntax [is different in the node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) than for the shell, which is the syntax you are using.

```js
db.collection("collection_name").findAndModify(
    { _id: _id },     // query
    [],               // represents a sort order if multiple matches
    { $set: data },   // update statement
    { new: true },    // options - new to return the modified document
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

There is a separate function for [`.findAndRemove()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandremove)

Comment: Perfect! Its working fine but I wonder why specifying sort is mandatory even if blank and we don't have same syntax as provided in mongodb wherein we can specify the key/values..

Comment: @RakeshGoyal it's just implemented this way in the driver and there are not alternate signatures available. Other libraries that wrap this one offer alternate signatures, or implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation for the `remove` parameter of the `findAndModify` function states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

> **remove: `<boolean>`:**
>   Must specify either the **remove** or the **update** field. Removes the
>   document specified in the **query** field. Set this to **true** to remove the
>   selected document . The default is false.

The default value is false so you don't have to provide it at all.

I believe the issue is that you are supplying *both* `update` and `remove` parameters. Try removing  the `remove` parameter.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't provide much info... Are you getting any errors?