# MongoDB command to find a single document and have a conditional statement in the update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

this has me stuck for a while now and I could really use some guidance from some SO experts. As title states, I want to find one document with a provided **_id**, and in the update have a conditional statement which checks if a field exists. If it doesn't I want to **$set** it and initialize a user ID array. If it does exist I want to run the **$push** command and push my userid into this field.

I tried to follow this stackover post with no results:
[Mongodb findAndModify node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648610/mongodb-findandmodify-node-js?newreg=986dbc956734473390002b41df60d335)

This is my code:

```
db.collection("tweets").findAndModify(
    { '_id': tweetId },                               //query
    [],                                               //blank sort parameter
    {                                                 //update
        $cond: {                                      //*
          if: { $ne: "likes" },                       //*
          then: { $set: { "likes": [tweetId] } },     //*
          else: { $push: { "likes": tweetId } }       //*
        }                                             //*
    },                                                //*
    { new: true },                                    //return modified
    function (err, valid) {                           //callback function
        console.log("In db update function");
        if (err) {
          db_updateLikes_cb(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(err, valid);
        db_updateLikes_cb(null, valid);
      }
    );
```

UPDATE:
In order to run a query with the "_id" you need to run mongodb's ObjectId function. This function needs to be imported into your .js file in Express/Node. Below is the code I used to get the query working.

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
var o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(tweetId);
db.collection("tweets").update({ '_id': objId }, { $push: { "likes": userId     } }, function () {
//do something
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without any conditional checking.  You can use $push for a key that doesn't exist.

```
db.getCollection('tweets').findAndModify({
    query: {"_id": ObjectId("58b1998ad0a0e5bb2331caa4")} ,
    update:{ $push: { "likes": ObjectId("58b1998ad0a0e5bb2331caa4") }}
})
```

They issue was your syntax was wrong.  findAndModify requires you tell it what each step is (query, sort, remove, update, etc).  The other thing is make sure the tweetid you are passing is BSON.

See the most recent mongodb docs for more info.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I was getting frustrated and instead ran a updateMany command to force all documents with a blank likes field. Do you know which method would have been better in terms of resource management?

Comment: Adding a likes field ahead of time will incur some disk storage overhead since those json bytes have to be stored on disk.  Do those extra bytes of storage matter?  Maybe.  You'll have to consider it for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

according to mongodb documentation the third parameter should be remove please check this once, I dont know much about iam still learning it hope it helps
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/][1]

```
 db.collection.findAndModify({
        query: <document>,
        sort: <document>,
        remove: <boolean>,
        update: <document>,
        new: <boolean>,
        fields: <document>,
        upsert: <boolean>,
        bypassDocumentValidation: <boolean>,
        writeConcern: <document>,
        collation: <document>
    });
```

Comment: if it's a reference, it should be a comment

Comment: Thanks @vijay-kumar , this set me on the right track. I'm no longer getting an error when running the command and am receiving a 200 response. My issue now is the update is not happening, something is wrong with my update statement :(

Comment: Make sure your tweetid is cast to BSON -  ObjectID(tweetid).  Test your query with just a find first.  Make sure that part is working.