# mongodb / nodejs: findandmodify method not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have below json data and want to update the value according to the condition

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fce2d4c7b2ea2e79ercvju4"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "token": "jwt_token_value",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fce2d4c7b2ea2e79ercvjk0"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "token": "jwt_token_value",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd0d45tjd82a02dd0f17fc4"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "token": "jwt_token_value",
    "isActive" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have managed the things as below.

```
let update = await UserDetails.findAndModify(
    { userId: 1, token: token },
    [],
    {$set: { isActive: 0 }},
    { new: true }
);
```

=> This query should update the last json collection key of `isActive` to 1. But it is not updating the values any how. What the things that I am doing wrong ? It is not throwing me any error as well to debug.

I am following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648693/5624578

Answer (score 0):

You can include the query identifiers to specify what each section is doing like this:

```
let update = await UserDetails.findAndModify(
    query: { userId: 1, token: token },
    update: {$set: { isActive: 0 }},
    upsert: true
);
```

Comment: It throws an error for those identifiers like `Cannot find name 'upsert'` https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/5802747/3e0e8facbc0679542afec318071587d9